# Force LESS to import a file twice

Tags: css, less, prepros

I am building a variable-driven LESS framework in which a child theme can override variables set in the parent theme. This framework includes responsive design, so variables have different values set for every media query. In order for the media query specific variables to take effect, the same styles that create the main layout have to also exist within the media queries. To make this as dynamic as possible, I have created layout less files that I want to import at every media query. Unfortunately, LESS only imports styles once and ignores all subsequent imports of the same file.

Here's the gist what it looks like:

style.less:

```
@import "variables"; // has the variables for the main layout
@import "variables-calculations";  // has all the dynamic element size calculations that change with the defined variables
@import "layouts";  // has all of the styles that incorporate the variables
@import "responsive-tablet-wide";
```

media-query-tablet-wide.less

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  @import "variables-responsive-tablet-wide";  // has all the variables for the current breakpoint
  @import "variables-calculations";  
  @import "layouts";
}
```

The resulting output for the media query? Empty:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {

}
```

I am using LESS compiler Prepros.

How can I force LESS to compile "layouts" twice? Or 5 times, for that matter.

Comment: Just in case there's `@import (multiple)` statement to force it to import more. But indeed that's not what you actually need for this particular use-case, see [@Bass Jobsen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20527637/2712740).

Comment: Actually, what you're suggesting is exactly what I need. The other suggestion just makes things messier.

Comment: Well, I can't say for sure without seeing "variables" internals but I suspect that it's most likely you're trying to use those variables in an iterative way (so then you will face more problems since LESS variables just do not work that way). But if it's not your case - cool - I'm glad my comment helped.

Comment: The cool thing about LESS variables is that you can define them differently within different scopes. For example: If I have a global page width of 1100px, I can set the variable again to 950px within a media query and it only affects the styles that incorporate it within that media query. That's why I want to import the same styles at every media query.

Answer (score 1):

I should define your variables in one file and append the target / device to it to discriminate between them

so variables should define:

```
@var1: 15;
@var1-tablet: 30; 
etc.
```

Main reason, see http://lesscss.org/:

> When defining a variable twice, the last definition of the variable is
>   used, searching from the current scope upwards. This is similar to css
>   itself where the last property inside a definition is used to
>   determine the value.

Comment: I am intentionally using this behavior to my advantage. Instead of having 4 variables for every value, I have one variable and only change its value within the scope I need to. This also helps with having less technical people work within the framework - no additional variable names to remember.

Comment: I don't know enough / nothing from your framework, to tell you are right or not. I think understanding open `variables-responsive-tablet-wide` to edit, or edit `@vars-responsive-tablet-wide` in .. will have the same level of difficulty.

Comment: I added another comment above to explain why I use the same variable names: if you have a variable that is declared outside of any brackets, then change the value of the variable within some brackets (like a media query) the new value only gets applied to the variable as it is used within the brackets. Outside, it reverts to the original value.